# Error: transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I know this questions asked a lot but I can't find any solution that solved my problem...
I'm getting this error:

```
 app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

when I'm running with the terminal, working with react native, on Mac...

This is my build gradle files:
/app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

 def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.X"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
   }
  }

dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-picker')
implementation project(':react-native-device-info-2')
implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
implementation project(':react-native-device-information')
implementation project(':react-native-fcm')
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation project(':react-native-svg')
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
implementation project(':react-native-config')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'

 }


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'libs'
   }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

and this is my android/build.gradle:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
   repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
 }

//com.android.ddmlib.DdmPreferences.setTimeOut(50000)

 allprojects {
   repositories {
            // Add jitpack repository (added by react-native-spinkit)
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
   //maybe this is unnecessary 

  }
 }

ext {
 compileSdkVersion = 28
  targetSdkVersion = 28
  buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
  supportLibVersion = "28.0.0-rc02"
  googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
  oreoEXPERIMENTAL = "yes"
 }

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28
            buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
            }
           }
          }
         }
```

I have been trying many solution I have seen but non of them work, I have been playing with the versions of the buildTool and the sdk and no solution yet.

I spent all day for trying find solution...
Thank you so much for the help!

adding the stackTrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 44 more
 Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.BuildConfig
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:114)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.BuildConfig
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:95)
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: just seen that yesterday, in another question (not indicating which library it is, does not help with an answer). https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues ...you should at least add the stack-trace, else this is quite a theoretical question, which barely could be answered.

Comment: @MartinZeitler how can I run the command 'react-native run-android' with stack trace on the terminal? I have been trying but didn't succeed

Comment: think it would be `npm run android`, executed in the project's directory.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I added the stack trace, hope it will help

Comment: replace implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0' to implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the stack-trace hints for ...

> CompilationError: Program type already present: com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.BuildConfig

which means, that either the class is being referenced twice - or that it's caused by a duplicate dependency. I'd have that `task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs` under suspicion and/or the contents of the `libs` directory - because the dependencies themselves do not mention that class, at all.

Comment: I had the com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo twice... delete one of them solved the problem